# DateTime filtering on microsoft.graph.chatMessage

Tags: microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to pull recent messages in a chat. My Graph query is as follows

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/chats/{chatId}/messages?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime gt 2022-07-27T07:13:28.000z
```

The query is valid but I get the following response

```
The query specified in the URI is not valid. Query option 'Filter' is not allowed. 
To allow it, set the 'AllowedQueryOptions' property on EnableQueryAttribute or QueryValidationSettings.
```

This message seems like a server side error/message. Is it possible to perform DateTime filtering on MSGraph Endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

According [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/13562), the endpoint

```
GET /me/chats/{chatId}/messages
```

does not support filtering.

Only the endpoint

```
GET /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages/delta
```

supports filtering by `lastModifiedDateTime` and operator `gt` but it only goes back max 8 months.